# Align something in a box with the sentence?

Tags: horizontal-alignment

i would like to know if it is possible, using `boxedminipage`, to align what is in a box ? 
Here follow my code; i would like the mu to be on the same line as the sentence.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3.5cm}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % provide a more open "look"
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage {boxedminipage}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}


Therefore, we have \begin{boxedminipage}[poslb]{6,5cm}$\hat{\mu}=2ln(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i)-${\large $\frac{3ln(n)}{2}-\frac{ln(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2)}{2}$}\end{boxedminipage}\\ \\


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just use an `\fbox` AND a `minipage` (with `t` option), instead of a `boxedminipage`.  I also used the `\ln` operator, instead of `ln`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-1.cm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3.5cm}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}

\usepackage{array} % for "\extrarowheight" macro
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt} % provide a more open "look"
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}

\begin{document}
Therefore, we have \fbox{\begin{minipage}[t]{6.5cm}$\hat{\mu}=2\ln(
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i)-${\large $\frac{3\ln(n)}{2}-\frac{\ln(
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2)}{2}$}\end{minipage}}\\ \\
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ABazigal The `boxedminipage` package seems very old (1992) and thus, perhaps, unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\boxed`, instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


Therefore, we have
$
\boxed{
  \hat{\mu}=
  2\ln\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\Bigr)-
  \frac{3\ln(n)}{2}-
  \frac{\ln\Bigl(\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\Bigr)}{2}} 
$

\end{document}
```

[image: whatever]

Possibly better

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Therefore, we have
$
\boxed{
  \hat{\mu}=
  2\ln\Bigl(\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\Bigr)-
  \frac{3\ln(n)}{2}-
  \frac{1}{2}\ln\Bigl(\,\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\Bigr) 
}
$

\end{document}
```

[image]